# creating column alias using function in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, alias

I have this table

```
sales(productid, sales_date)
```

I want to get the monthly sales count for last 12 month.

How can I generate the month name on the column alias (without hard coding)?

I tried this :-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee777/9

But I want the result table in this format

```
productid   Oct-12  Nov-12  Dec-12  Jan-13  Feb-13  Mar-13  Apr-13  May-13
1           0       0       3       4       2       8       2       11      
2           0       5       6       8       2       0       0       0
```

I tried to give the column alias using function `DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%M')` but it is 
syntax error.

```
select productid,sum(if(DATE_FORMAT(sales_date,'%Y%m')=
DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curdate(),interval 12 month),'%Y%m'),1,0)) 
`12 Months Before`,
sum(if(DATE_FORMAT(sales_date,'%Y%m')=
DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curdate(),interval 11 month),'%Y%m'),1,0)) 
`11 Months Before`,
sum(if(DATE_FORMAT(sales_date,'%Y%m')=
DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curdate(),interval 10 month),'%Y%m'),1,0)) 
`10 Months Before`,
sum(if(DATE_FORMAT(sales_date,'%Y%m')=
DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curdate(),interval 9 month),'%Y%m'),1,0)) 
`9 Months Before`,
sum(if(DATE_FORMAT(sales_date,'%Y%m')=
DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curdate(),interval 8 month),'%Y%m'),1,0)) 
`8 Months Before`,
sum(if(DATE_FORMAT(sales_date,'%Y%m')=
DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curdate(),interval 7 month),'%Y%m'),1,0)) 
`7 Months Before`,
sum(if(DATE_FORMAT(sales_date,'%Y%m')=
DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curdate(),interval 6 month),'%Y%m'),1,0)) 
`6 Months Before`,
sum(if(DATE_FORMAT(sales_date,'%Y%m')=
DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curdate(),interval 5 month),'%Y%m'),1,0)) 
`5 Months Before`,
sum(if(DATE_FORMAT(sales_date,'%Y%m')=
DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curdate(),interval 4 month),'%Y%m'),1,0)) 
`4 Months Before`,
sum(if(DATE_FORMAT(sales_date,'%Y%m')=
DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curdate(),interval 3 month),'%Y%m'),1,0)) 
`3 Months Before`,
sum(if(DATE_FORMAT(sales_date,'%Y%m')=
DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curdate(),interval 2 month),'%Y%m'),1,0)) 
`2 Months Before`,
sum(if(DATE_FORMAT(sales_date,'%Y%m')=
DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 month),'%Y%m'),1,0)) 
`1 Months Before`
from sales
group by productid;
```

How can I get month and year as alias (eg:- Oct-12) in place of `12 Months Before` , `11 Months Before` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql doesn't have `PIVOT` so you have to use conditional `SUM()`.

There are two options:

1. You do it manually if number of periods are finite and known beforehand
2. You can use dynamic SQL to generate the query on the fly and then execute it

A query for option1 might look like this

```
SELECT productid
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%Y%m') = '201210' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `Oct12`
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%Y%m') = '201211' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `Nov12`      
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%Y%m') = '201212' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `Dec12`
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%Y%m') = '201301' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `Jan13`
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%Y%m') = '201302' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `Feb13`      
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%Y%m') = '201303' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `Mar13`
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%Y%m') = '201304' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `Apr13`
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%Y%m') = '201305' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `May13`      
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%Y%m') = '201306' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `Jun13`
 FROM sales
WHERE sales_date BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2013-06-30'
GROUP BY productid
```

Sample output:

```
| PRODUCTID | OCT12 | NOV12 | DEC12 | JAN13 | FEB13 | MAR13 | APR13 | MAY13 | JUN13 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     1 |     1 |     0 |     0 |     2 |     1 |
|         2 |     1 |     1 |     1 |     0 |     0 |     1 |     1 |     1 |     2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee777/24)** demo

---

Now a version for option 2 using dynamic SQL (`PREPARE`, `EXECUTE`)

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, ''%Y%m'') = ''',
      DATE_FORMAT(period, '%Y%m'), ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `', DATE_FORMAT(period, '%b%y'), '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%Y-%m-01') period
      FROM sales
     WHERE sales_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 11 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') AND CURDATE()
     GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%Y-%m-01')
) s;

SET @sql = CONCAT
('SELECT productid, ', @sql, ' 
    FROM sales
   WHERE sales_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 11 MONTH, ''%Y-%m-01'') AND CURDATE()
   GROUP BY productid'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output is the same.

```
| PRODUCTID | JUL12 | AUG12 | SEP12 | OCT12 | NOV12 | DEC12 | JAN13 | FEB13 | MAR13 | APR13 | MAY13 | JUN13 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |     1 |     2 |     1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     1 |     1 |     0 |     0 |     2 |     1 |
|         2 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     1 |     1 |     1 |     0 |     0 |     1 |     1 |     1 |     2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee777/34)** demo

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to get the product-wise monthly sales count for last 12 month without hard-coding any date. The query should work for any date.

Comment: That can be easily implemented. Now given that we are executing this query today what exact period you want `2012-06-29 to 2013-06-29` or `2012-06-01 to 2013-06-29` or `2012-05-01 to 2013-05-31` (meaning full 12 calendar months)`? Your question is unclear on that.

Comment: Just ignore days. include 2012-07 to 2013-06 .

Comment: See updated answer. It's obviously only for a version with dynamic SQL.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help :) BTW IMHO the next logical step is to wrap this query up in a stored procedure to hide the complexity and don't clutter client side code.